# How to Resume Yolov3 training?

Tags: yolo, resuming-training

I am new to deep learning, I have a yolov3 model that I have been training on my custom data. Every time I train, the training seems to start from scratch. How do I make the model continue its training from where it stopped last time?
The setup I have is the same as [this repo](https://github.com/YunYang1994/TensorFlow2.0-Examples/tree/master/4-Object_Detection/YOLOV3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.load_weights(path_to_checkpoint)` just after the model is defined at `line 41` in `train.py` and continue training where you left off

Comment: Thank you! I am assuming the 'path_to_checkpoint' would be './"yolov3"' ? Because the training generates a 'yolov3.data-00000-of-00001' file, and I can't input that name into the load_weights method. I see in the script that do model.save_weights(./"yolov3").